# Strange error on download using googleapis 7.1.0

Tags: node.js, download, google-api

I am downloading a file from Google Drive using nodejs module googleapis 7.1.0.  When I do authentication or retrieve metadata, everything goes fine.

When the download is finished and the application is supposed to end, I get two different outcomes, both seem to be wrong.

In Windows, the program just hangs indefinitely and produces no output, no exception. I just hangs.

On FreeBSD, I get the following stack trace:

```
buffer.js:377
    throw new Error('toString failed');
    ^

Error: toString failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:377:11)
    at BufferList.toString (/usr/home/jvavruska/gdrive/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/bl.js:166:33)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/home/jvavruska/gdrive/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1035:36)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/home/jvavruska/gdrive/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1003:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
```

I use node 4.4.5 on both machines (Windows 10 and FreeBSD 10) and the same version of googleapis (7.1.0).

The final function that does the download is here. `name` is read from file metadat using *get* API, `auth` is the auth object created from google.auth.OAuth2, `googleDrive` is proxy of google.drive('v3') and `google` is from google = require('googleapis') :

```
function googleDownload ( name, fileId, auth, downloadDirectory ) {
   downloadDirectory = downloadDirectory || 'c:\\playground' ;
   var targetFileName = path.join( downloadDirectory, name );
   var dest = fs.createWriteStream(targetFileName);
   console.log(`Starting download of ${fileId} as ${name}`);
   googleDrive.files.get({
      fileId: fileId,
      auth: auth,
      alt: 'media'
   }, 
  (err, response) => {
     if(err) { console.log("Download error: ", err);}
     else { console.log("Download completed."); } 
   })
   .on('end', () => { console.log('All data received.'); })
   .on('finish', () => { console.log('All data written.'); })
   .on('close', () => { console.log('Connectin closed.'); })
   .on('error', (err) => { console.log('Error during download: ', err); })
   .pipe(dest);
}
```

By looking into the code I was not able to find a direct link between the place where the error is thrown and what was actually supposed to happen. I just noticed that the googleapis bundle seems to duplicate a number of methods or functions available in NodeJS API but cannot say what is the impact on the error.

Comment: P.S. the last event that fires is actually the `end` event. `finish` or `close` never occur.

Comment: size of file ? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2767

Comment: 1.3 to 2.2 GB, varies

Comment: BTW is the file size significant here? First, the file is not going to be converted to text, it is saved as binary file. Second, the download uses input.pipe(output), so am I assuming right that pipe() method will make the writable stream always receive just one chunk of data from the readable stream?